# How can I change the formula of one cell based on the value in a different cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

**COLUMN D**: Dropdown list of values

**COLUMN E**: `IF` function returning different values depending on COLUMN D contents

[image: 0]

I have the functionality described above working properly. My problem is that I want the `IF` function in COLUMN E to return a ***working formula*** rather than a *value*.

Right now the `IF` function only returns the actual formula text rather than using the formula itself within the cell. I'm assuming that this is because the `IF` function can only provide values, not formulas, as outputs.

[image: 0]

Is there a better approach or function I can use to **insert a completely different, operational formula into COLUMN E depending on the value listed in COLUMN D**?

Your help is appreciated.

EDIT: An example of my problem can be found on the following sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m_-rLniq-il7jL0ilWZWxh4cYq65DW2V2uQwtFgQLLA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: what is your formula?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Here's an example:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1m_-rLniq-il7jL0ilWZWxh4cYq65DW2V2uQwtFgQLLA

Columns B and C dynamically update depending on what's selected in Column A. I accomplish that by using VLOOKUP to pull data from specific columns in the data sheet.

But there are multiple shipping rates, so when the "Shipping To" value is changed, I want to automatically change the adjacent formula in Column E.

Using the IF function doesn't provide an operational formula -- just plaintext. I want a comparable function that actually changes the active formula.

Answer (score 0):

- paste in **B2** cell:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, data!$A:$C, {2, 3}, 0)))
  ```
- paste in **E2** cell:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B&D2:D, 
   TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
   IF(LEN(data!A2:A), "♦"&data!A2:A&data!B2:B&
   IF(LEN(data!D2:G), REGEXEXTRACT(data!D1:G1, "^..")&"♠"&data!D2:G, ), ))
   ,,999^99)),,999^99)), "♦")), "♠")), 2, 0)*1))
  ```

  [image: 0]
- ### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AUm3qAokGPw83fOa6cMdJPlHdiI8c7TYw7ePR_-A3TY/edit#gid=0)